# Extracting table count, image count in .msg file using python in MAC

Tags: python-3.x, macos, outlook, email-attachments, win32com

I am trying to extract table count, image count from .msg files in python.

I was using win32com package previously and it was giving the expected output. **I am trying to replicate the same in Mac but not able to find relevant packages to get the required output**

Working code in Windows:

```
import win32com.client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\\Users\\sowmiyan\\Sample.msg")


html = msg.HTMLBody
soup = BeautifulSoup(html )
tables = soup.findAll("table")
count_tables=len(tables)

count_attachments = msg.Attachments.Count
image_format_list=['png','jpg','tif','gif']
count_images = 0

if count_attachments > 0:
                for item in range(count_attachments):
                    if msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1).Filename.split(".")[-1] in image_format_list:
                        count_images+=1


print(count_tables)
print(count_images)
```

Could somebody provide some pointers to make it work in **MAC**